# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in Place holder

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I found the error in this

```
ph = (PlaceHolder)row.FindControl("phs");
```

ASP.Net code:

```
<PagerTemplate>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><asp:PlaceHolder ID="phs" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</PagerTemplate>
```

Comment: plz post your whole code

Comment: Either row or row.FindControl("phs") is/returns null. A more detailed description would help though!

Comment: <PagerTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phs" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </PagerTemplate>

Comment: @Piushshukla you need accept the answer, if it is helpful. last time also you not accepted my answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

If this line is throwing an exception:

```
ph = (PlaceHolder)row.FindControl("phs");
```

... then that suggests that `row` is null. If it's not null, then *even if the method calls returns null*, it shouldn't throw an exception. You can cast a null reference with no problems<sup>1</sup>.

So work out whether `row` can possibly be null somehow, and either fix your code so it can't, or check whether or not it *is* null before using it.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are three obscure alternatives I can think of, mind you:

- `row.FindRow` could actually be referencing a field or property within `row` which is a delegate, but that delegate is null
- `row.FindRow` could return null and the casting expression could be performing some user-defined cast which is throwing the exception
- The assignment could be a property setter call which is throwing the exception

Only the first of these would really be *that line* throwing the exception, mind you - and I think it's staggeringly unlikely.

Comment: @Piushshukla: How do you do what? At the moment we have no idea where `row` is coming from, so we don't know whether it's legitimate for it to be null or not. You need to be able to think about your own code, for yourself.